# how can i use the array in where statement in laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

**here is the data**

```
req[
    {
        "_id": "123",
        "_ar_id": "111",
        "_val": "10",
        "ar_date": "2023-02-02"
    },
    {
        "_id": "1234",
        "_ar_id": null,
        "_val": "0",
        "ar_date": "2023-02-02"
    }
]


$validator = Validator::make($req->all(), [
            'req.*._id' => 'required',
            'req.*._val' => 'required',
            'req.*.ar_date' => 'required',
        ]);
        
if ($validator->fails()) {
     return response()->json(['stat' => 0,'msg' => $validator->errors(), 'data' => "Please input required details" ]);
        }
```

**since i validate the request, how can i use it in where to ?**

**here's the code**

```
$record = ArRecordCount::where('ar_list_id', $list_id)->where('ar_date', $ar_date)->first();
```

**and if has record then it will update, if no record then delete**

Comment: If there is no record there's nothing to delete.

Comment: there is, cuz if they inserted and set the value to 0 and the previous value is 10, then it will delete to database, to me to lesser the data in DB

Comment: My point is that `->first()` will return either object (if found), either null if no record. Therefore `$record` variable if assigned with null, you can not make action delete over that variable.